# Usage of & in xquery concat

Tags: xquery, exist-db

How can I use `&` (the ampersand character) in an XQuery `concat` statement? I'm using eXist DB and this works:

```
concat("Marvin ", "and", " Peter")
```

but this doesn't:

```
concat("Marvin ", "&", " Peter")
```

I'm getting the error: `expecting '"', found '&'`

Escaping the ampersand with a `\` doesn't work.

Comment: Funnily enough the notification mail from SO gives the solution away. Your question is shown as: `How can I use &amp; (the ampersand character) in an Xquery concat statement? I'm using eXist DB and this works: concat("Marvin ", "and", " Peter") but this doesn't: concat("Marvin ", "&amp;", " ... `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `&` is the escape character for [XML character and entity references](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references), it cannot be used as a literal character in either XML or XQuery strings. You have to use an entity to encode it. You can either use the predefined `&amp;`, or reference it via its Unicode codepoint with `&#[...];` (decimal) or `&#x[...];` (hexadecimal):

```
concat("Marvin ", "&amp;", " Peter"),
concat("Marvin ", "&#38;", " Peter"),
concat("Marvin ", "&#x26;", " Peter")
```

Comment: For improved readability you can define the variable `let $amp := fn:codepoints-to-string(38)` .